# How to attach debug information into an instruction in a LLVM Pass

Tags: c++, clang, llvm

I am trying to collect some information from my `LLVM` optimization pass during runtime. In other words, I want to know the physical address of a specific IR instruction after compilation. So my idea is to convert the `LLVM` metadata into `LLVM` DWARF data that can be used during runtime. Instead of attaching the filename and line numbers, I want to attach my own information. My question falls into two parts:

1. Here is a code that can get the Filename and Line number of an instruction:

   `if (DILocation *Loc = I->getDebugLoc()) { // Here I is an LLVM instruction
     unsigned Line = Loc->getLine();
     StringRef File = Loc->getFilename();
     StringRef Dir = Loc->getDirectory();
     bool ImplicitCode = Loc->isImplicitCode();
   }`

But How can I set this fields? I could not find a relevant function.

2. How can I see the updated Debug Information during (filename and line numbers) runtime? I used `-g` for compiling but still I do not see the Debug Information.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you need it [setDebugLoc()](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Instruction.html#ae8f5bf5cc06f696b52c709677df00fbf) and the info is only included in the result if you include enough of it. [The module verifier](http://llvm.org/doxygen/Verifier_8h.html) will tell you what you're missing. These two lines might also be what's tripping you up.

```
module->addModuleFlag(Module::Warning, "Dwarf Version", dwarf::DWARF_VERSION);
module->addModuleFlag(Module::Warning, "Debug Info Version", DEBUG_METADATA_VERSION);
```

Comment: I cannot find the relation between Debug Information and the Module Verifier. Does it just verify that that Debug Information of instructions are complete? Also how the last two lines can trip me? should I add these two lines to my pass and check the result?

Comment: The module verifier checks, among other things, that the debug information for a module is consistent and can be used to produce valid DWARF output. And If you don't add those two module flags, or something like them, then you get no DWARF debug output at all.